# How to save my To-Do list in localStorage and make sure the unfinished To-Dos remain on the page after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

As one of my bootcamp projects, creating a To-Do list where the user should be able to add a new to-do, mark a to-do as completed, and remove a to-do is 50% of it. The last half is saving the To-Dos in localStorage and making sure when the page refreshes, the To-Dos remain on the page. This last part has been giving me trouble. I understand I need to use localStorage.setItem(), localStorage.getItem(), JSON.stringify(), and JSON.parse() in my code - I just haven't figured out where. I have diligently googled, searched stackoverflow, and YouTubed and experimented for the past 3 days straight, but I have yet to find a solution that works with what I already have. So here I am asking my first question on SO as a final resort. I would love to find a solution that works with what I have already written, if possible. I am still very new to this so I am hoping to get some advice on my code. Thank you, in advance!

```
const form = document.querySelector('#add-item');
const input = document.querySelector('#add');
const toDoList = document.querySelector('#todolist');
const savedToDos = [];

// Removing List and Toggling Priority
toDoList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON') {
        e.target.parentElement.remove();
    } else if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        e.target.classList.toggle('priority');
    }
});

// Adding and Removing
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(input.value);

    const newAdd = document.createElement('li');
    const removeAdd = document.createElement('button');
    removeAdd.innerText = 'Done!';
    newAdd.innerText = input.value;
    newAdd.appendChild(removeAdd);
    toDoList.appendChild(newAdd);
    input.value = '';

    console.log(localStorage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating an object that defines your todo item. For example:

```
let fooTodo = {
  title: "sleep",
  completed: false
}
```

Then, given an array of todo items like the above, you can read and write them to localStorage. For example:

```
let todos = [{name: "foo", completed: false}, {name: "bar", completed: true}];
localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos)); // saves to localStorage
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")); // prints `todos` from localStorage
```

As to where to put this, you can load everything from localStorage on window load.

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  // load from localStorage
  // populate page
});
```

Comment: Thank you @dwosk for your response! I understand your solution, now I just need to see how and where I can apply it to my code. I'll let you know once I figure it out!